# Solving a three variable equation

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, systems-of-equations

I have three given values, suppose a=1.86, b=2.6 and c=4.2. Now I have to figure out x,y,z such that

1. $x\gt 0,y\gt 0$ and $z\gt 0$
2. $x+y+z=1$
3. $a*x\gt 1, b*y\gt 1$ and $cz\gt 1$

I need a generalized solution steps for this to implement in programming.

Thanks.

Comment: I think It's related to linear programming and operational research. Try to look at some texts about them.

Comment: Thanks for the this. Anything else I can refer to?

Comment: I haven't studied much about this field and so I don't know good refrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we need all of $ax, by, cz$ to be greater than $1$, given a set of $(a,b,c)$ we want $x,y,z$ to be bigger than $\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c}$.

To find a generalized set of steps, first calculate $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$. If this sum is greater than $1$, **there are no solutions for $x,y,z$.** This makes sense, because if we let $a,b,c$ to be $0.0001$ or some small number, $x,y,z$ would all have to be large and they would not sum to $1$, but we need $x+y+z=1$.

If it is less than or equal to $1$, then simply picking some number larger than $\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c}$ for $x,y,z$ will do.

If $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}<1$, we calculate $1-(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})$. Call this value $n$. Find the value of $\frac{n}{3}$ and add it to $\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c}$ and you will surely have values of $x,y,z$ that sum to $1$.

Comment: Thanks for so elaborative answer. I am done with my task.

Comment: x+y+z=1 is fulfilled by the above explanation. Can you show me some ligth towards getting the other conditions true i.e. a*x>1 and so on...

Comment: If we pick $x$ to be a number larger than $\frac{1}{a}$, then $ax > a\cdot \frac{1}{a} = 1$. So the conditions will be trueas well. This is, of course, granted that $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{x > \frac{1}{a} \Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{a} + X}\\
{y > \frac{1}{b} \Rightarrow y = \frac{1}{b} + Y}\\
{z > \frac{1}{c} \Rightarrow z = \frac{1}{c} + Z}
\end{array}} \right.$  where $0 < X,Y,Z$

$   \Rightarrow \frac{1}{a} + X + \frac{1}{b} + Y + \frac{1}{c} + Z = 1 \Rightarrow X + Y + Z = 1 - \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{c}$ $\hspace{.3cm}$(*)

(*) is an equation of surface where cut each axis in $1 - \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{c}$. 
Your solution is all the point on this surface which that lie on the first quadrant.

Comment: can you give me an idea how can I go for X Y and Z

Answer (score 0):

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x > \frac{1}{a} \Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{a} + \varepsilon \\
y > \frac{1}{b} \Rightarrow y = \frac{1}{b} + \varepsilon \\
z > \frac{1}{c} \Rightarrow z = \frac{1}{c} + \varepsilon 
\end{array} \right.$ where $0<\varepsilon$.

$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{a} + \varepsilon  + \frac{1}{b} + \varepsilon  + \frac{1}{c} + \varepsilon  = 1 \Rightarrow \varepsilon  = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{{3a}} - \frac{1}{{3b}} - \frac{1}{{3c}} = {\rm{0}}{\rm{.1053}}$

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: Since $x>1/a$ I just add small value to make it equal. i.e. $x>1/a$ -> $x=1/a+\epsilon$. Actually it just gives you one solution not all the solutions.

Comment: x+y+z=1 is fulfilled by the above explanation. Can you show me some ligth towards getting the other conditions true i.e. a*x>1 and so on...